# Error when setting up a Hangfire recurrent job on application startup

Tags: .net-core, scheduled-tasks, hangfire

I'm trying to set up Hangfire recurrent jobs on application startup (in `Startup.cs` of a .NET.Core web application), so that we can be sure that they are always registered. I managed to get it to work for a dummy job but I get a strange error for a more real test job:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Expression object should be not null.
   at Hangfire.Common.Job.FromExpression(LambdaExpression methodCall, Type explicitType)
   at Hangfire.RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(String recurringJobId, Expression`1 methodCall, Func`1 cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo timeZone, String queue)
   at WsApplication.Web.Startup.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Projects\boxman\aspnet-core\src\WsApplication.Web.Host\Startup\Startup.cs:line 163
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

This is what I have in my startup class:

```
        // Hangfire (Enable to use Hangfire instead of default job manager)
        services.AddHangfire(config =>
        {
            config.UseSqlServerStorage(_appConfiguration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
        });
        JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage(_appConfiguration.GetConnectionString("Default"));

        // Register recurring jobs on startup
        var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var offHireJob = sp.GetService<UnsetContainerIsBookedPerOffHireJob>();
        // Test job 1 - this gets registered fine!
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Test", () => Console.Write("Test"), Cron.Minutely);
        // Test job 2 - This line triggers the error!
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(UnsetContainerIsBookedPerOffHireJob.JobId, () => offHireJob.Run(), Cron.Minutely);
```

And this is my actual test job:

```
public class UnsetContainerIsBookedPerOffHireJob : ApplicationService
{
    public readonly static string JobId = nameof(UnsetContainerIsBookedPerOffHireJob);
    private readonly IRepository<ContractLineMovement, int> _contractLineMovementRepository;

    public UnsetContainerIsBookedPerOffHireJob(
        IRepository<ContractLineMovement, int> contractLineMovementRepository
    ){ 
        _contractLineMovementRepository = contractLineMovementRepository;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Logger.Debug("Running UnsetContainerIsBookedPerOffHireJob.Run()");

        var offHirequery = from contractLineMovement in _contractLineMovementRepository.GetAll()
                           where contractLineMovement.ContractWorkFlowEventId == (int)ContractWorkFlowEventValues.OffHire
                           select contractLineMovement;

        foreach (var offHire in offHirequery)
        {
            Logger.Debug("Processing offhire with ID: " + offHire.Id + " and Date: " + offHire.HireDate);
        }
    }
}
```

I've found [the piece of code in Hangfire's source code](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/commit/a1126b822e4b7ef9ea208ffba5a0f3ef06ae29e8) which raises this exception but I still don't really understand why this expression

> () => offHireJob.Run()

would cause a problem. It looks basic to me. Maybe I am missing something basic?

Or is there a better way to register my recurrent jobs once at an application level?